# Is the phrase "grow up in my career" OK?

Tags: sentence-construction, usage, phrasal-verbs

The following:

> In spite of having quite good working conditions, I'm looking for
> opportunities to grow up in my career.

Does it sound ok? I'm not sure about the second part of the sentence, especially the phrase "to grow up in my career".

Comment: "Advance" is just a slightly more sophisticated way of saying "move forward". And it's "career", not "carreer".

Answer (score 12):

Drop the "up", and I think it sounds fine for U.S. English:

> I'm looking for opportunities to grow in my career.

Comment: 'Advance' sounds more natural than 'grow'.  @Stephie's comment should be an answer.

Answer (score 9):

The phrase "grow up" is usually used for children growing up into adults. Sometimes an adult might be told "Oh grow up!", meaning that the speaker thinks they're behaving like a child. You definitely don't want to use that phrase in your sentence.

You can talk about wanting to grow in your ability or skills. Usually we say "advance" in your field or career, as Stephie suggested. Post graduate degrees are sometimes called "advanced degrees", so advance has a sense of moving toward a higher level of skill or knowledge or responsibility.

Answer (score 1):

It makes sense, but the wording is awkward. You could try being more specific about what you hope to do. For instance:

> I am hoping for an opportunity to improve my interpersonal skills

or

> I hope to develop my understanding of the industry

Sentences like this make it clear that you know what you want to achieve, and give a clearer idea of you as  a person and how you could become more valuable over time.

Answer (score 1):

The professional way to say "grow up" is "mature" (it's both a verb and an adjective, here we use it as a verb).

"I'm looking for opportunities to mature professionally" works well and retains the exact original meaning.