# Does this justification regarding my two-year gap in academics sound positive or negative?

Tags: word-usage, connotations

**It is a justification regarding my two-year gap in academics for a job interview.**

I took a gap of 2 years after my 12th(*intermediate college*) for IIT-JEE(*entrance examination for the admission in premier engineering colleges of India like IIT*).

I failed to crack it in first two attempts.

In the third attempt, the admission policy changed due to which I got a very low rank.

During that time of my gap, I gained three qualities in me

1. To analyse and research things minutely
2. Thinking based on logic and reasons
3. Self-learning capability

**So how about if I justify my gap like this:**

> I took two years off to prepare for the IIT-JEE but was **not successful**
>   in achieving that goal. It taught me that one must pursue a goal for
>   the sake of learning along the way, not just for achieving the goal. I
>   inculcated a habit of analysing the problems, research about them in
>   detail, think logically and self-learning ability.

I unsure about the word "not successful".
How to make the whole justification sound more positive?

Comment: I don't think you should *try* to make the failure sound "more positive"; if I were your reader I would be more impressed by the straightforward presentation than by any attempt to make it "more positive"--the positive part comes in your **response** to the failure. ... But that is a matter for [workplace.se], not ELL.

Comment: I was of two minds, but I do now think this is a proofreading or editorial question, unfortunately. Importantly, though: is fluency in English a requirement for admission, @PiyushMalvia ?

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'm sure it's not proofreading -- in the Help Center's words, "the source of concern is clearly specified".

Comment: Editorial, then? The "not successful" portion is obvious, but I'm not sure how to answer the second question without sending it to _rewrite!_

Comment: @P.E.Dant I think that this question has enough context, and a specific concern. It's difficult for learners to know sometimes whether their phrasing will be poorly received for some reason that is not obvious from the dictionary definition of the words they put together. For example [Is grow up in my career OK?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/61731). I think this is on-topic.

Comment: Food for thought, certainly. I still wish we understood how critical fluency in English is to succeeding in this particular examination.

Comment: @P.E.Dant I'm not sure I follow you. Surely if fluency was important, the interviewers will make their own determination.

Comment: @P.E.Dant yes, English plays a huge role in impressing the interviewer. Sometimes it fills the gap of weakness in technical skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might present your explanation of the two-year gap as follows:

> I took two years off to prepare for the IIT-JEE. Although I did not achieve my goal of passing the examination, I found that the time spent in preparation benefitted me in many other ways. I developed the ability to study without supervision. I learned that one must pursue learning for its own sake, not just to achieve a specific goal. I cultivated the habits of analysing problems, researching them in detail, and thinking logically.

Comment: Thank you so much for resolving my issue with such a detailed answer :)

Answer (score 0):

> I took two years off to prepare for the IIT-JEE but was **not successful** in achieving that goal.

The phrase "not successful" in this sentence is neutral to me. The main problem is "that goal" is referring back to "preparing for the IIT-JEE" and so the sentence doesn't exactly say "I didn't pass the test" although readers would likely assume that's what you meant.

You might add what your goal was specifically"

> I took two years off to prepare for the IIT-JEE but was not successful in achieving my goal of (passing the examination/entering IIT).

Also, inculcated is a fairly rare word (at least in AmE) - P.E. Dant's suggestion of using "cultivated" in its place is a good one.

Comment: Also, _inculcated_ almost always refers to the other; the sense is that a virtue is inculcated in someone through drilling ("forced in" in the Latin) by an outside agency. He would have to say _inculcated in myself,_ and the verb is not used there with its customary affect.